# Why use the data parameter of html5 history.pushState?

Tags: ajax, html, pushstate

I have been building a single page app, and figuring out how to use the html5 history object to save and retrieve the history, but I am not sure I see any advantage (at least in my case) of using the data part (first param) of pushState over simply retrieving the url and executing the page logic based on that.

I suppose it could be useful if I only needed to change one single variable in my page, like the color of something. But I need to do the same thing to my page whether someone has typed the full url and entered it, or if this is a history object, so having the URL itself is enough for me to be able to trigger the actions I need.

Am I missing something important here? Can anyone explain why I would want to save a bunch of info to the data parameter of pushState?